# Jira Tempo - Synchronize deleted hours with external system

Tags: jira-rest-api, time-tracking

I'm trying to insert in my system hours loaded in Jira (with add-on [Tempo Timesheets](https://www.tempo.io/tempo-timesheets-agile-time-tracking-plugin-for-jira)) using the API of Tempo.

#### Steps

1. I try to insert in my system the last inserted hours in Jira without problem.
2. I edit in Jira some already exported hours to my system, and I can get all time entries Synchronized with my system.

#### Problem

The problem is when I delete some hours in Jira, when I call the Tempo API the hours are no longer displayed in the result, neither as deleted nor as modified.
So I can not know which ones I have to delete in my system

Does anyone know how to get deleted hours in Jira in a range of dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When delete some worklog (time entry) from Tempo, internally change the worklog description to "Worklog DELETED in Jira" and the hours value change to "0.0"

If these two things happen, we can determinate that the worklog has been deleted.